# Break SQL results by number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How would I convert the below list into multiple rows based on the qty but grouped by the item?

Current results.

```
ITEM     QTY
-----    ----
12345     1
12346     2
12347     3
```

This is the desired results

```
ITEM     QTY
-----    ----
12345     1
12346     1
12346     1
12347     1
12347     1
12347     1
```

This is the query

```
SELECT a.item,sum(b.qty) as qty

FROM table1 a, table2 b 
WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id 
group by a.item
order by a.item_id
```

Comment: Just making sure I understand: you have output 1 and you want to get to output 2? Also, the query you wrote, it produces output 2, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by applying the `rownum` to the records:

```
select t1.item, qty / qty as qty
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select rownum rn, item
  from yourtable
) t2
  on t1.qty >= t2.rn
order by t1.item
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53e00/32)